# How can to do shape math with bing maps?

Tags: bing-maps

If I have two shapes displayed on Bing-Maps can I do any set Math?

What I really want is to take two intersecting shapes, determine a 3rd shape for the intersection and then reduce the the original shapes to exclude the intersection.

I actually have the intersection shape so the key bit is taking a 'bite' out of the original shapes.

Reason for doing this is currently displaying the intersection as a third layer (to give a specific colour) produces a largely occluded map, what with part of the transparent shape1 and shape2 and the intersection all covering the same bit of the map.

If I could 'cut-down' the two main shapes only the intersection shape would colour/cover that part of the map.

Comment: I am most interested in solutions that use the Bing maps API but any solution will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there are out of the box solutions in the Bing Maps API. I have done something similar in the past with Bing Maps API and `SqlGeography Class` though.  Its easy to loop through the points of our Bing Polygons, therefore we can plot them into SqlGeography [Polygons](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.opengisgeographytype.aspx) or SqlGeometry [Polygons](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.opengisgeometrytype.aspx).

You will need the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` to make use of this class, but it is free with SqlExpress.(Note that you do not actually need SQL Server installed, you just need to reference the DLL)

You can use the [SqlGeography Class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stintersection.aspx) (or [SqlGeometry Class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx)) to find intersecting shapes and points. Perhaps have a look at `STIntersection`   Method, According to MSDN STIntersection will;

```
"Returns an object representing the points where a SqlGeography instance intersects another SqlGeography instance."
```

Once you have the object representing the shape were a SqlGeography instance intersects another, you know you need to somehow adjust any points from the compaired instances that lie withing the SqlGeography instnace returned by `StIntersection`.

Here is a [simular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415242/subtracting-a-sql-server-geometry-from-another) where Peter uses [STDifference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stdifference.aspx). To subtract the two shapes.

I'll provide you with a c# example I made quickly for the Intersection.  I had a lot of trouble finding any code examples for anything that wasn't purely SQL Server based.

```
  SqlGeography Shape1 = new SqlGeography();
    SqlGeographyBuilder geographyBuilder1 = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
    geographyBuilder1.SetSrid(4326);
    geographyBuilder1.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Polygon);
    geographyBuilder1.BeginFigure(47.4275329011347, -86.8136038458706);
    geographyBuilder1.AddLine(36.5102408627967, -86.9680936860962);
    geographyBuilder1.AddLine(37.4928909385966, -80.2884061860962);
    geographyBuilder1.AddLine(38.7375329179818, -75.7180936860962);
    geographyBuilder1.AddLine(48.0932596736361, -83.7161405610962);
    geographyBuilder1.AddLine(47.4275329011347, -86.8136038458706);// Remember last point in the polygon should match the first
    geographyBuilder1.EndFigure();
    geographyBuilder1.EndGeography();

    Shape1 = geographyBuilder1.ConstructedGeography;

    SqlGeography Shape2 = new SqlGeography();
    SqlGeographyBuilder geographyBuilder2 = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
    geographyBuilder2.SetSrid(4326);
    geographyBuilder2.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Polygon);
    geographyBuilder2.BeginFigure(47.4275329011347, -86.8136038458706);
    geographyBuilder2.AddLine(36.5102408627967, -86.9680936860962);
    geographyBuilder2.AddLine(37.4928909385966, -80.2884061860962);
    geographyBuilder2.AddLine(47.4275329011347, -86.8136038458706);
    geographyBuilder2.EndFigure();
    geographyBuilder2.EndGeography();
    Shape2 = geographyBuilder2.ConstructedGeography;

    SqlGeography IntersectedShape = Shape1.STIntersection(Shape2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can draw shapes with the new [GeoRSS](http://georss.org/simple) feature - it supports line, boxes, polygons and circles. GeoRSS was designed as a lightweight, community driven way to extend existing feeds with geographic information. Also check out [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/)

Comment: here is a review of their service http://www.georelated.com/2012/02/cloud-web-map-api-services-reviewed_19.html

Comment: Both of those seem to be data formats, not APIs to operate on shape data.
The review also does not reveal any methods to operate on shape data.